# Finding linearly independent subsets?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the following set of vectors, l need to eliminate the vectors which are linear combinations of others to get a subset of linearly independent vectors. But l am a bit confused.

$$ ( 1, (\sin x)^{2} ,\cos(2x), (\cos x)^{2} ) $$

I can eliminate $$\cos(2x) $$ but l think the other three vectors can all be expressed as a linear combination of one another.

Are all the three subsets below the correct answers.

$$ ( 1, (\sin x)^{2} ) \text{  or  } ( 1, (\cos x)^{2} ) , ((\cos x)^{2} ,(\sin x)^{2} )$$

Comment: Do you know a linear relation of $\sin(x)^2$, $\cos(x)^2$ and $1$?

Comment: @Dietrich It was a mistake, l have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ and $1=\cos^2x+\sin^2x$, you will have to eliminate two of your vectors in order to get a linearly independent set.

Comment: So these 2  answers are correct,                       
$$ ( 1, (sinx)^{2} )   or   ( 1, (cosx)^{2} ) $$

Comment: Yes, both of them are correct.